# Mysqldump command not found

Tags: command-line, path, mysql

I want to export my database and i am using this code:

```
mysqldump -p -u markazo_b markazo_b > /tmp/file.sql
```

But SSH show this error:

> `-bash: mysqldump: command not found`

How i fix this problem?

Answer (score 17):

After reading your conversation, I found the solution (for me, at least). It was a permissions issue.

Issuing `which mysqldump` in the terminal shows `/usr/bin/mysqldump`.

When I then issue `cd /usr/bin/` and afterward `mysqldump` I receive the same indications you were seeing: `mysqldump: command not found`.

Inside `/usr/bin` I then issued `sudo mysqldump` and received:

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

Try that and see if it helps.

Edit: too long, didn't read: `sudo mysqldump` may work. (May be a permissions issue.)

Comment: in short, you may need to use **/usr/bin/mysqldump**

Comment: Yes, but I answered in such a manner so that the @okancelik might understand how to find his own particular directory.

Comment: Looking back on this question, I was hasty to agree with you, @fedmich. In short, a person may need to issue `sudo mysqldump`. My answer was verbose in order to verify the command is available for execution.

Answer (score 15):

The solution I found is adding MySql's installation directory to PATH

Steps:

1. Find where MySql is installed
2. Add the bin directory of MySql installation to PATH

(In the terminal),

```
locate mysqldump

export PATH=$PATH:MY_SQL_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY/bin
```

MY_SQL_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY is the directory you found by `locate mysqldump`:
Example

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql-5.6.23-osx10.8-x86_64/bin
```

Answer (score 10):

You probably don't have the MySQL `/bin` folder on your PATH.  Change to your mysql /bin folder and try the command again.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand your suggest. Please explain detail, thank you.

Comment: Try `cd /usr/bin/` then run `mysqldump` again

Comment: The same error. My ssh screen in this picture ; http://i.hizliresim.com/A2W3jL.jpg

Comment: What does `which mysqldump` tell you?  That's the directory you want to be in.

Comment: Sorry, My english is bad. I dont understand your suggest.

Comment: Of course this was my problem. I added `export PATH=$PATH:\usr\local\mysql\bin`  to `~/.profile` file, or run `PATH=$PATH:\usr\local\mysql\bin` in terminal.

Answer (score 8):

For OS X and MAMP (localhost) open Terminal and run

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Add the following code (make sure to change the **-uroot -proot** by the username and password you have for mysql):

```
alias mysqldump='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump --host=localhost -uroot -proot'
```

Once added, Press Ctrl + O to save then Ctrl X to leave the editor, now run on the terminal

```
mysqldump dbname > dump_name.sql
```

That worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 4):

My solution: (On windows) 
1, Right click to your computer ==> Properties ==> Advanced system settings ==> on tabs "Advanced" click Environments Variables ==> on System variables find "Path" and click "Edit". 
2, Finally, you copy your bin folder of your mysql to that. 
Ex: `D:\LEARN\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\bin` 
3, Restart cmd and try your command again. 
Nice..

Comment: 1, From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
2, Choose Properties from the context menu.
3, Click the Advanced system settings link.
4, Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
5, In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, add location of folder `mysql/bin` to the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
Ex: my location is `D:\LEARN\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\bin`

Answer (score 2):

For mac users, look into `/usr/local/`, this is most likely where mysql is installed. There may be two installations. I chose the one without the version number in the name.

You need to add the path of your mysql installation to your bash profile by adding `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin` to `~/.bash_profile`. Can try running `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin` if adding export to `~/.bash_profile` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying using git bash, please try CMD **xampp/mysql/bin** then run

> mysqldump -u root -p DbName> name_to_downlaod.sql

Answer (score 0):

I just did the following steps and that fixed the issue for me!

1- sudo nano ~/.zshrc
2- Added the following to the file: {export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin}
3- restart your terminal (not sure this is needed, but I did it to make sure!)

Hope this will fix someone's issue!