# Grunt Wordpress Deploy - mysqldump command not found

Tags: mysql, ssh, gruntjs

I am trying to use grunt-wordpress-deploy to automate my Wordpress deployment using Grunt.

After configuring my grunt file and setting up mysql users on remote server I tried to do a test deploy but returned the following error:

**ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/bin/sh: mysqldump: command not found' at line 1**

I believe this is a PATH problem but am not sure if is a problem with the mysql config on my local or remote server and also how I would go about resolving this. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That looks like the *actual string* `/bin/sh: mysqldump: command not found` is being fed to mySQL as SQL code. There's probably a problem in how `mysql` is called.

Comment: mysqldump -h <%= host %> -u<%= user %> -p\"<%= pass %>\" <%= database %>

Comment: that looks like thos mysqldump command in the grunt plugin files

Comment: Ah. Then `mysqldump` is not installed on the server, or can't be called for some reason. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342734/mysqldump-command-not-found

Comment: i can run the mysql dump on both my local and remote server so it must be installed

Comment: ah, hang on I cannot run the mysqldump command on my local