# PHP mysqldump creates empty file

Tags: php, mysql, exec

I'm trying run exec with mysqldump in my PHP file. It doesn't work, I'm even trying to use it without variables like this:

```
exec('mysqldump --user=xx --password=xx --host=xx db settings > /output/dump5.sql');
```

It creates empty file.

But when I run this command in ssh, it works. Why?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this: https://gist.github.com/micc83/fe6b5609b3a280e5516e2a3e9f633675

Comment: Yes, at first I tried exactly that

Comment: It returns array(1) { [0]=> string(32) "sh: mysqldump: command not found" }

Comment: check your permissions on the database.

Comment: check this string as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29094299/11073547

Comment: But in SSH it works with the same user

Comment: that's because on SSH you've the permission to dump the sql on the other hand when you dump your sql using php then it conflicts with your permissions and that's why you're seeing an empty dump.

Comment: Exec runs with user www-data

Comment: So I have to check chmod or mysql permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do this from php script ?

I assume that you want to do the backup frequently, so maybe adding it to cron job will better solution.

Comment: Yes, I want to output INSERT statements on the page.