# Improve Export speed of database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a function that exports the mysql database. I researched many ways to do that. I have arrived to the function below. The problem with this is the exporting is so slow my database size is only 10mb. Is there a way to make this faster or improve it?

```
public function backup_database($tables = '*'){
    if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
        $return = '';

        if($tables == '*') {
            $tables = array();

            $sql = $this->db_connection->prepare('SHOW TABLES');

            if($sql->execute()){
                while($row = $sql->fetch()){
                    $tables[] = $row[0];
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
        }

        foreach($tables as $table) {
            $result = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM ' . $table);
            $result->execute();
            $num_fields = $result->rowCount();

            $return .= 'DROP TABLE ' . $table . ';';

            $row2 = $this->db_connection->prepare('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table);
            $row2->execute();
            $row2 = $row2->fetch();

            $return .= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++){
                while($row = $result->fetch())
                {
                    $return .= 'INSERT INTO '. $table .' VALUES(';
                    for($j = 0; $j < $num_fields; $j++){
                        $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                        $row[$j] = preg_replace("/\\n/","\\n",$row[$j]);
                        if (isset($row[$j])) { $return .= '"'. $row[$j] .'"' ; } else { $return .= '""'; }
                        if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return .= ','; }
                    }
                    $return .= ");\n";
                }
            }

            $return .="\n\n\n";
        }

        if (!file_exists('database_backups')) {
            mkdir('database_backups', 0777, true);
        }
        
        $filename = 'database_backups/db-backup-'.time().'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql.gz';
        $handle = fopen($filename,'w+');
        $gzdata = gzencode($return, 9);
        fwrite($handle,$gzdata);
        fclose($handle);
        
        return '1';
    }
```

Comment: Have you thought about using `mysqldump` for this?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular yes I tried using exec command on PHP but it is not working

Comment: Well, if you want speed then `mysqldump` is the way to go. It's built for exactly this job. You might do better debugging that.

Comment: your title shows the import the mysql tables but you want to export the table

Comment: There's no way that you can get a high-speed dump via PHP with it reading and writing the rows.

Comment: `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` might work somewhat fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export all database tables at once, you can just use this php code ---

```
  $backup_file = "/var/www/html/DB_backup/evidyaa" . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.sql'; //this would the path of the filename for backup
   $command = "mysqldump --user=dbuser --password=dbpass --host=dbhost ". "dbname > $backup_file";
   
   passthru($command);
  echo 'done';
```

If you are using windows then command would be

```
$backup_file = "/var/www/html/DB_backup/evidyaa" . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.sql'; //this would the path of the filename for backup
       $command = "c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe --user=dbuser --password=dbpass --host=dbhost ". "dbname > $backup_file";
```

Comment: I am getting this error "'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: you did not specified, you are using linux or windows?

Comment: Sorry I am using windows

Comment: Maybe you need `$command = 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump.exe ...'`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342734/mysqldump-command-not-found/24342756

Comment: okay then please check where is mysql.exe file, Please check i have edited the answer for windows using xampp or the path given by kmoser.

Comment: It's probably pointless to wrap `mysqldump` inside PHP, as well as dumping into `/var/www/html`...

Comment: Use forward slashes even on Windows; MySQL is smart enough to tilt them.  With backslashes, you risk them being used as escapes.